# Finish a fragment with onBackPressed true?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment(TimerToAnswer) that I implemented `onBackPressed()` of a `ActionBarActivity`. Does Fragment can't return when isVisible true because there is a timer to answer a question. After the question is answer in Fragment(TimerToAnswer) I make redirect to other Fragment(ChooseQuestion) to choose other question to answer. In this stage when I pressed button back of device its return to Fragment(TimerToAnswer) again and I don't wanna that. For this problem, I'm trying `finish()` the Fragment(TimerToAnswer) but I can't do it.

I tried
`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();`
or
`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Here how I'm trying

**ActionBarActivity**

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{


@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {   
        TimerToAnswer tt = (TimerToAnswer)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TimerToAnswer");

        if(tt != null && tt.isVisible()){
            return;
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    }
```

**Fragment TimerToAnswer**

```
public class TimerToAnswer extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

   if(answer){
      FragmentTransaction ft;
                    Fragment frag;

                        frag = new ChooseQuestion();
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);                      
                        ft.addToBackStack("back");
                        ft.commit();

                        removeFrag();       
   }

   private void removeFrag(){
            //getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's returning to your `TimerToAnswer` fragment when the user presses back from `ChooseQuestion` is because of this line:

`ft.addToBackStack("back");`

What that does, [as per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29):

> Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will **reverse its operation** when later popped off the stack.

To fix this, just remove that line.